# How to minimize "where()" on Laravel query builder. If all table columns are all the same values

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Is there a way to minimize calling ->where() on laravel query builder?

Sample Table:

| name | item1 | item2 | item 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| David | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| David | 1 | 2 | 2 |

I want to remove a specific record with all the table columns containing 0 value without removing the other records.

My query is this.

```
DB::table('users')->where('name', 'David')
                  ->where('item1', 0)
                  ->where('item2', 0)
                  ->where('item3', 0)
                  ->delete();
```

Is there a way to minimize calling->where()? Just like in whereIn('columns',[1,2,3,4]) but in columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an array of conditions to the where function. Each element of the array should be an array containing the three arguments typically passed to the where method:

```
$conditions=[
  ['name','=', 'David'],
  ['item1','=',0],
  ['item2','=', 0],
  ['item3','=', 0],
]
DB::table('users')->where($conditions)->delete();
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks. I can use this technique on all of my code to avoid repetition